# What exactly does the --install-base parameter to ./setup.py install mean?

Tags: python, distutils

I try to install a python module with a custom installation layout.

From the documentation I gathered that I could do

```
python ./setup.py install -f --install-base="/home/hstock/tmp/python" \
                        --install-purelib=modules \
                        --install-scripts=bin \
                        --install-data=data \
                        --install-platlib=modules \
                        --install-headers=include
```

and this should install modules to `/home/hstock/tmp/python/modules` - however it seems that `install-base` is ignored and modules are installed to `./modules`.

Is this a bug or did I get the documentation wrong?

(This is python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu Lucid)

**Update:**

The module I want to install is self made, the `setup.py` is very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='ilogtoolbox',
    provides=['ilogtoolbox'],
    version='0.6.3.1',
    packages=['ilogtoolbox'],
    requires=['daemon'],
    scripts=['prunedirs', 'logstoexternal']
    )
```

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? If so you could maybe post your own answer to this question?

Comment: Any news on this? FWIW, I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 (amd64) with Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all those --install-* arguments accept simple string templates. Have a look at python's stdlib [distutils.command.install code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.6.8/Lib/distutils/command/install.py). You will see that defaults are like '$base/Lib' or '$base/Scripts'.

So for your use case it will look like this:

```
python ./setup.py install -f --install-base="/home/hstock/tmp/python" \
                        --install-purelib='$base/modules' \
                        --install-scripts='$base/bin' \
                        --install-data='$base/data' \
                        --install-platlib='$base/modules' \
                        --install-headers='$base/include'
```

And since --install-lib actually sets both purelib and platlib it can be shortened a little:

```
python ./setup.py install -f --install-base="/home/hstock/tmp/python" \
                        --install-lib='$base/modules' \
                        --install-scripts='$base/bin' \
                        --install-data='$base/data' \
                        --install-headers='$base/include'
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation it looks like you have used this correctly - what is the module? Is it possible that the module author did not correctly utilise distutils?

Comment: I wrote the module myself. I posted the setup.py above. I think this is a normal way of using distutils.

Comment: @Hanno can you include the content of your distutils.cfg file? Is anything in here specified by absolute path? Generally things look correct so I'm trying to find GOTCHAs...

Comment: I agree that your usage just follows what the docs say!  Can you publish the whole project somewhere?